# Convert datatype of existing data from Char to DateTime with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am relatively new to SQL Server and I am trying to update the datatype of about 3000 records from a `Char` to `Datetime` so I can use the DATEDIFF function. I created a view that achieves the conversion but what I think I need to do is alter the data in the origin table.

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(8), TRANS_ACCOUNTINGDATE_ALLCAMPAIGNS_2010_ALLPROCESSINGACCOUNTS_ALL)) 
FROM Accounting;
```

What I think I need to do is an alter table and iterate over each row performing the conversion. Trying to change the data type using the GUI is not working for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The datatype is an attribute of the COLUMN, not just of the data inside the column.  You can't put `datetime` data into a `char` field - that's the purpose of data types!

You need to add a new field and run an `UPDATE` statement to populate it with your converted data.  Then you can drop the original field and rename your new one to the original name.

Comment: Actually, as long as all of the values in the CHAR column can be converted to a DATETIME you can simply run an ALTER TABLE...ALTER COLUMN command and it will run (tested in SQL 2008)

Comment: @Tom - good to know, I never tried to change from `char` to `datetime` on a populated field.  Personally I still prefer doing it with a new field so I have control over the transformation.